# Batch file commands to open different commands in new windows

Tags: windows, internet-explorer, google-chrome, batch-file

For one of my job functions, I have to have multiple instances of a program open. I need 6 IE windows, 1 Chrome, and one internal, web-based program that launches via IE. I wrote a batch file already that opens everything just fine and my team all uses it, but it opens all the windows in IE tabs which we then have to copy/paste the urls into new windows.

I am trying to have them all open in individual windows.

Here's what I've done so far (this works, just not how I'd like):

```
@echo off

Start "------" "http://url.com/program.html"
Start "------" "http://url.com/program.html"
Start "------" "http://url.com/program.html"
Start "------" "http://url.com/program.html"
Start "------" "http://url.com/program.html"
Start "------" "http://url.com/program.html" 
start "------" "http://url.com/program.html"
start "------" "http://url.com/program.html"
```

I've put generic urls and hyphens for program names in the interest of corporate security, but I think it still gets my point across. Each one of these opens in separate tabs in 1 IE window.

What do I need to add to this .bat in order to open each line in separate IE windows and 1 of them in a Chrome window?

Thanks!
-Ghaz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Start "------" "c:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe" http://url.com/program.html
Start "------" "c:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe" http://url.com/program.html
Start "------"  "%userprofile%\appdata\local\chromium\Application\chrome.exe" http://url.com/program.html --new-window
```

Comment: Nailed it. Thanks dude!